# JBPM 6 configuration with maven

Tags: jboss, netty, drools, jbpm, kie

I am developing an application using Jbpm 6 rest api. I am trying to use following code to  interact via REST with the remote runtime.
  // Create REST session

```
RemoteRestSessionFactory restSessionFactory = new RemoteRestSessionFactory(deploymentId, deploymentUrl, user, password);
RuntimeEngine engine = restSessionFactory.newRuntimeEngine();
KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
```

I am trying to add jbpm-kie-services with maven in jboss 8.1, but after adding that jar , the application is not deploying. Please can anyone help me to configure above code with Jbpm 6 required maven libraries.

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the kie.remote client:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
          <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
          <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I started using the remoting api the other day. I used the maven dependency that @Grady G Cooper mentioned, but I received a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.auth.AuthState.update error while attempting to connect. This was caused by a dependency issue that I found [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243425).  Below is my pom file to get around this issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
       <!--exclude old version causing issue-->
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- add proper versions -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Remote REST API, you will need to use jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml to import aditional dependencies.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>    
            <dependencies>
                    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true" meta-inf="import" />
                    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" export="true" meta-inf="import" />
                    <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" export="true" meta-inf="import" />
            </dependencies>
    </deployment>
```

Your pom.xml file should look like

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom.brms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-drools</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.bom.brms}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.kie</groupId>
<artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-audit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Source https://access.redhat.com/solutions/784863